# SyntaxError compressing wirecloud

Tags: django, fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I am trying to setup an own wirecloud instance on CentOS 6.6 with PostgreSQL on another VM running Ubuntu Server 14.04.1. Therefore I followed [this guide](https://wirecloud.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation_guide/) which worked fine untill I came to the django configuration.

Every time I try to run the compress statement i get the following error:

```
Compressing... /usr/local/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scss/types.py:1065: FutureWarning: String got a bytes type 'platform' -- this will no longer be supported in pyScss 2.0
  .format(value)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/usr/local/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/compressor/management/commands/compress.py", line 281, in handle_noargs
    self.compress(sys.stdout, **options)
  File "/usr/local/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/compressor/management/commands/compress.py", line 228, in compress
    rendered = parser.render_nodelist(template, context, node)
  File "/usr/local/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/compressor/offline/django.py", line 123, in render_nodelist
    return node.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 840, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/usr/local/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 854, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1196, in render
    _dict = func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/wirecloud/platform/templatetags/wirecloudtags.py", line 46, in wirecloud_bootstrap
    endpoints = get_wirecloud_ajax_endpoints(view)
  File "/usr/local/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/wirecloud/platform/plugins.py", line 199, in get_wirecloud_ajax_endpoints
    endpoints += plugin.get_ajax_endpoints(view)
  File "/usr/local/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/wirecloud/platform/core/plugins.py", line 550, in get_ajax_endpoints
    {'id': 'LOGIN_VIEW', 'url': build_url_template('login')},
  File "/usr/local/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/wirecloud/platform/plugins.py", line 411, in build_url_template
    possibilities = resolver.reverse_dict.getlist(view)
  File "/usr/local/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 315, in reverse_dict
    self._populate()
  File "/usr/local/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 267, in _populate
    for pattern in reversed(self.url_patterns):
  File "/usr/local/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 365, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 360, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/local/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/opt/wc/imt/imt/urls.py", line 7, in <module>
    import wirecloud.platform.urls
  File "/usr/local/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/wirecloud/platform/urls.py", line 24, in <module>
    from wirecloud.platform import views
  File "/usr/local/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/wirecloud/platform/views.py", line 42, in <module>
    from wirecloud.platform.workspace.utils import get_workspace_list
  File "/usr/local/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/wirecloud/platform/workspace/utils.py", line 519
    data_ret['preferences'] = {preference['name']: cache_manager.get_variable_data(iwidget, preference['name']) for preference in iwidget_info['preferences']}
                                                                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Help on this one would be really appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As said by @Alasdair, this because you are using Python 2.6. Current installation guide of WireCloud states that you can use python 2.6, but in fact you cannot, because the use of the dictionary comprehension and because other dependencies used by WireCloud don't support python2.6 in their latests versions.

Our current plan is to remove python 2.6 from the installation guide. If you want you can add comments into the [issue ticket](https://github.com/Wirecloud/wirecloud/issues/66) created by Alasdair.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data_ret['preferences'] = {preference['name']: cache_manager.get_variable_data(iwidget, preference['name']) for preference in iwidget_info['preferences']}
```

This is a dictionary comprehension. They were added in Python 2.7. You are running Python 2.6, so you are getting a syntax error.